# Poisson Regression with GAM but with multiplicative lambda

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, generalized-additive-model

Consider the following model

$$ a_i \sim \text{Poisson}(\, m(x_{1,i},x_{2,i}) \, b_i \,)  $$

I'd like to predict $m$ as a function of predictor variables $x_1, x_2$. You can think of $a$ as the "after" variable, and $b$ as the before variable, and $m$ as a multiplicable factor (or growth rate) which is determined by the predictor variables. In my data set $m$ is potentially quite non-linear, and there are a considerable number of zeros for $a$. For example, consider the following reproducible toy data set in R.

```
set.seed(1)

#simulate fake data
  n <- 200 #number of data points
  x1 <- rnorm(n)/2                 #predictor 1
  x2 <- rnorm(n)/2                 #predictor 2
  before <- rpois(n, lambda = 50)  #initial quantity before, it undergoes a process
                                   #based on predictors, leading to data "after"

#create "after" data, Poisson distributed with lambda = before * some coefficient
#coeficient is a nonlinear function of the predictors

  multiple <- 20 - 60 * x1^2 + 12 * x2  #factor, when not zero

  #assign negative values, for the factor, zero
    il0 <- which(multiple <= 0) 
    ig0 <- which(multiple > 0)
    multiple[il0] <- 0 

  #generate dependent variable data, "after"  
    after <- rep(0,n)
    after[ig0] <- rpois(n = length(ig0), lambda = before[ig0]*multiple[ig0])
```

I was thinking to do Poisson regression with a GAM, but the issue is that lambda is m*b in this case, and I want to predict m for any given set of predictors, not the actual value for lambda. Not sure how to do this. Ideally would like to do it in R.

Comment: To make this reproducible, you need to add a call to `set.seed()`

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen done

Comment: Do you literally mean that $m(x_{1i}, x_{2i})$ is a smooth interaction effect of the two covariates, or something else? If you do mean a smooth interaction, this looks like a varying coefficient model, where $m()$ is a smoothly varying surface that multiplies the covariate $b_i$. That model can be fitted in *mgcv* (with a constant term as well) as `m <- gam(y ~ te(x1, x2, by = b), data = my_data, method = 'REML')` assuming `x1`, `x2`, and `b` are all continuous covariates.

Comment: @GavinSimpson x1 and x2 are continuous, m is smooth, but b is count data, so not continuous. Could think of it like b is the number of cells at time 0 and a is the number of cells at time 1, where m represents how quickly they multiply. I should say m having a lot of zeros, might make it not really smooth come to think about it, but maybe approximately smooth.

Comment: @GavinSimpson it also needs to be constrained to only make positive predictions for m, even for x1 and x2 new data, outside of the data range of the sample.